# How to call ICommand.CanExecute in this case?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

OK. Here's the scenario. This is WPF + MVVM (.net 4.0) application:

1. View: Has a `DataGrid` and two buttons Move Up / Move Down, which are supposed to move selected record up or down in the `DataGrid`. Both the grid and the buttons use XAML-based binding.
2. ViewModel: Has a public property of `DataView` type to which my `DataGrid` will bind. Then there are two `ICommand` implementations listed below. The two buttons will bind to these two commands. Last but not the least there are two functions called `MoveUp()` and `MoveDown()` that do the obvious.
3. Two `ICommand` implementations: In each command, `CanExecute()` returns whether selected record can be moved up or down respectively, and `Execute()` actually moves the record by calling ViewModel's `MoveUp()` and `MoveDown()` functions I described above. These command objects get a reference of VM object in their constructors.

First off, I want to know if this architecture correct and in line with MVVM pattern? Secondly, the problem at hand is that my buttons do not get enabled/disabled when I change selected record in the `DataGrid`, which brings up 2 sub-questions:

1. Who calls `CanExecute()` and when?
2. How can I call it manually? I have tried `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` after reading some other SO questions, but that didn't help either.

Here's my `CommandBase` class, from which both my Command classes inherit:

```
internal abstract class CommandBase : DependencyObject, ICommand
{
    public virtual bool CanExecute(Object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public abstract void Execute(Object parameter);
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    protected void OnCanExecuteChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CanExecuteChanged(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of `ICommand` you using?

Comment: What do u mean by version? there is only one `ICommand` in `System.Windows.Input` (PresentationCore.dll 4.0.0).

Comment: Yeah I meant `DelegateCommand` or `RelayCommand` or your own derived implementation of `ICommand`?

Comment: mmm...not sure. I'm pasting my `CommandBase` class above. All my concrete command classes inherit from it.

Comment: `CanExecute` method always returning true from base class method. I hope you are setting it to actual `Predicate` in your concerete implementation of Command, otherwise command `CanExecute` willa lways return true and button will never be disabled.

Comment: The problem is that my buttons never get enabled! But yes, I'm overriding it in the concrete classes and using correct condition in there.

Comment: I have tried to answer all your queries in my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to know if this architecture correct and in line with MVVM
>   pattern?

Yeah, that's completely in compliance with MVVM pattern.

---

> Who calls CanExecute() and when?

CanExecute() gets called whenever `CanExecuteChanged` event is raised.

Commands internally hooks to this event and *enable/disable button or any frameworkElement based on bool property returned by CanExecute delegate*.

---

> How can I call it manually?

First of all create `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method in your concrete implementation (if not already) so that it can be called manually. This will look like this:

```
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        EventHandler canExecuteChangedHandler = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (canExecuteChangedHandler != null)
        {
           canExecuteChangedHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Since in your case, you need to call `CanExecute()` whenever SelectedItem in dataGrid changes. I would suggest to bind `SelectedItem` of DataGrid to some property in your ViewModel and in setter, you manually call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` so that CanExecute can be called on your command instance.

---

However, there is another way if you don't want to manually call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method. You can hook to `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event which gets raised whenever `CommandManager` feels like that UI needs to be refreshed.

```
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
```

> RequerySuggested event Occurs when the
>   **System.Windows.Input.CommandManager** detects conditions that might
>   change the ability of a command to execute.

So, whenever `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` gets raised, it will eventually raises your `CanExecuteChanged` thereby calling `CanExecute` of your command. Hence enable/disable button based on bool returned by CanExecute delegate.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed input. One question: `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` is marked protected. My ViewModel will not be able to access it. No?

Comment: Right, i simply copied your `OnCanExecuteChanged()`. It should be public or may be internal whichever suits you best. Updated in an answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I ended up with `CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;` thing. It is working beautifully. Can't accept more than one answer, but it definitely deserves +1.

Comment: Just be aware that `CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;` will gets called most frequently whenever you still don't want to. (may be with any button click, lost focus or any GUI interaction). Rest definitely is your choice.!!

Comment: Just visited this after many years. Now that I understand WPF in more depth, I feel this one should be marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your 'OnExcuteChanged' with this...

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add
    {
        CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Super! Can you type some explanation too?

Answer (score 0):

I personally always use the implementation `RelayCommand` from Josh Smith:

```
internal class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        }

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }

        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Quote about `CanExecutedChanged` event from this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx):

> The CanExecuteChanged event, which is part of the ICommand interface implementation, has some interesting features. It delegates the event subscription to the CommandManager.RequerySuggested event. This ensures that the WPF commanding infrastructure asks all RelayCommand objects if they can execute whenever it asks the built-in commands.

In your case, this event did not work, and the object has not received information about the possibility of executing the command.